# Laravel 5.4: JWTAuth, ErrorException in EloquentUserProvider.php

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I am a newbie of laravel, so it might be my mistake. Using laravel with [tymondesigns/jwt-auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth)
 to verify user. I am watching this tutorial [Complete JWT-AUTH api with Laravel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VlJDPxTvUqk&list=PLZAiN3wmUtzUHBDUI6F5Ks3t-U-wVRIV2&index=1) and followed every step, the tymon package installation and logging in user. But i am getting this error. I posted code below, tell me if you need more code from any other file.

> ErrorException in EloquentUserProvider.php line 120: Argument 1 passed
>   to Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials() must be
>   an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of
>   App\User given

This is my user model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class User extends Model
    {
        protected $hidden = ["password"];
        protected $fillable = [
                                "id",
                                "name",
                                "password",
                                "mobile_number",
                                "gender",
                                "age",
                                "company_name",
                                "profile_image",
                                "email"
                            ];
    }
?>
```

This is my ApiAuthController.php

```
use JWTAuth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;

class ApiAuthController extends Controller
{
    public function authenticate(){
        $credentaials = request()->only('email', 'password');
        print_r($credentaials);

        try {
            $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentaials);
            if(!$token){
                return response()->json(['error'=>'invalid credentaials'], 401);
            }
        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            return response()->json(['error'=>'something went wrong'], 500);
        }
        return response()->json(['token'=>$token], 200);
    }
}
```

User store function in my UsersController:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $payload = json_decode($request->payload, true);

        $validator = Validator::make($payload, $this->rules);

        if ($validator->passes()) {

            $user = (new User())->fill($payload);
            if($user->save()){

                $response = [
                    "msg" => "User created",
                    "link" => "/api/users/" . $user->id
                ];
                return response()->json($response, 200);
            }

            $response = [
                "msg" => "An error occured"
            ];

            return response()->json($response, 404);

        } 
        else {
            return response()->json($validator->messages(), 404);
        }        
    }
```

In storing user request, payload is key and value is json object, the small sample object is given below:

```
payload={
  "name": "Alexa",
  "email": "alexa@gmail.com",
"password":"12345",
  "gender": "Male",
  "age": 24
}
```

Comment: a unrelated tip to this error: Remove the "id" from your fillable fields, you don't want your id to be massassignable. And your password should only be in the hidden array. not in de fillable one. And its Credentials instead of Credentaials .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your model

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
```

and change this line

```
class User extends Authenticatable
```

Edit :
Looks like you're storing passwords in plaintext. Add this to your user model.

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($value);
}
```

Comment: I also tried this, error was removed but i always get invalid credentials if i input the right credentials.

Comment: Share your code where you add the user to the database. I'm guessing you're storing the plaintext password directly. By default laravel's auth methods hash the password input for comparison.

Comment: i've updated the post, you can see above how i am adding user in database.

Comment: @MTA i edited my answer, check it. You're storing the password in plaintext instead of storing the password hash, but when you use JWT::attempt(), it in turn uses laravel's built in auth method which compares the hash of your input password. Therefore you get the invalid credential error. Add the setPasswordAttribute i've shown. Besides the episode 5 of the video series you linked shows you to use bcrypt hasher. Not sure how you missed that.